# How do I post to Django /accounts/login/ from mobile native application?

Tags: python, django, mobile

I use Django 1.6 and Python2.7 and develop web application.

I post there parameters from mobile native application.

csrfmiddlewaretoken
username
password

but, 403 FORBIDDEN was happened.

Could you tell me how to resolve it?

My urls.py is

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login1'),
```

And, my `/registration/login.html` template has `csrf_token`

```
<body style="margin-top: 5em;">
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal" style="position: relative; top: auto; left: auto; margin: 0 auto; z-index:1;">
        <div class="modal-header">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `@csrf` in your views or add `{% csrf_token %}` in your template.
And you can post data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And I use  `{% csrf_token %}` in my templates. But, I use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view. so, how to add add @csrf in the views?

Comment: `def login` has already had `@csrf_protect`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: I guess I need HEADER from client mobile phone